# Is there a better way to implement the const version of member function row() without using const_cast?

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, valarray

The example comes from the demonstration for use of *std::slice* and *std::slice_array*:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice_array

How should I properly define the const version of member function row()? The following code compiles but it uses *const_cast*. I would really appreciated it if you can give any suggestion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
class Matrix {
    std::valarray<int> data;
    int dim;
 public:
    Matrix(int r, int c) : data(r*c), dim(c) {}
    int& operator()(int r, int c) {return data[r*dim + c];}
    std::slice_array<int> row(std::size_t row) {
        return data[std::slice(dim*row, dim, 1)];
    }
    const std::slice_array<int> row(std::size_t row) const {
        return const_cast<std::valarray<int>&>(data)[std::slice(dim*row, dim, 1)];
    }
};
int main()
{
    Matrix m(3,3);
    int n = 0;
    for(int r=0; r<3; ++r)
       for(int c=0; c<3; ++c)
           m(r, c) = ++n;
    
    const Matrix m2(m);

    for(int r=0; r<3; ++r) {
        for(int c=0; c<3; ++c) {
            std::cout << m(r, c) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // non-const
    std::slice_array<int> isa = m.row(0);
    std::valarray<int> iva(isa);
    for (auto elem : iva) { std::cout << elem << std::endl;} 
    
    // const
    const std::slice_array<int> isa2 = m2.row(0);
    const std::valarray<int> iva2(isa2);
    for (auto elem : iva) { std::cout << elem << std::endl;} 

    return 0;
}
```

If the member function is defined as follows:

```
    const std::slice_array<int> row(std::size_t row) const {
        return data[std::slice(dim*row, dim, 1)];
    }
```

then following error message is produced:

```
valarray_demo.cpp:13:16: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type '__val_expr<__slice_expr<const std::__1::valarray<int> &> >' to function return type 'const std::slice_array<int>'
        return data[std::slice(dim*row, dim, 1)];
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/valarray:1149:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      '__val_expr<__slice_expr<const std::__1::valarray<int> &> >' to 'const std::__1::slice_array<int> &' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS slice_array
```

test on:
macOS Catalina;
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)

Answer (score 4):

Note that in return value type `const std::slice_array<int>`, the top level `const` qualifier is ignored by the compiler, so that the actual return type is `std::slice_array<int>`. [The same rule applies to function parameters.](http://www.dansaks.com/articles/2000-02%20Top-Level%20cv-Qualifiers%20in%20Function%20Parameters.pdf)

You probably want a slice to constant elements, not a constant slice to mutable elements.

---

[`std::valarray` doesn't offer slices to constant elements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_at):

```
std::slice_array<T> operator[](std::slice slicearr);
std::valarray<T>    operator[](std::slice slicearr) const;
```

The `const` version returns a copy of the elements and, hence, cannot be implemented to return a slice to constant elements at all.

---

`std::valarray` is an odd beast, long abandoned attempt at linear algebra support in the C++ standard library. For production code you may like to use Eigen library: [Eigen is a C++ template library for linear algebra: matrices, vectors, numerical solvers, and related algorithms](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).